# I want make my botton animate on fragment but i get an error in the load animation

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, animation

I want ass my application screen comes on my bottons to animate from button to place i know how to do it in an activity but in a fragment it having issues.

There is an error in the this that says this cannot be applied to fragment and when i put get context it does not animate. Please tell me what wrong.

This is my main fragment code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    samabtn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.samabtn);
    samabtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
            mainActivity.loadParrablesFragment();
        }
    });
    Lovebtn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Lovebtn);
    Lovebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
            mainActivity.loadChapter2Fragment();


        }
    });
    Adventurebtn=(Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Adventurebtn);
    Adventurebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
            mainActivity.loadAdventureFragmnet();

        }
    });
    menbtn=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.menbtn);
    frombottom=  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.frombottom);
    menbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MainActivity mainActivity=(MainActivity)getActivity();
            mainActivity.loadMysteryFragment();

        }
    });
```

i have tried get context now the error it gone but the animation i want does not work

Comment: they is an error in the this that says this canot be applied to fragment and when i put get context it does not animate

Comment: Improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the problem you're talking about happens on this line:

> ```
> frombottom=  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.frombottom);
> ```

Assuming I'm right about that, the problem is that the first argument to `loadAnimation()` must be a `Context`. Activities are Contexts, which is why this works when you do it inside an Activity. However, Fragments are *not* Contexts, so you can't pass `this` as the first argument.

Within a Fragment, the easiest way to get a Context object is to call `getContext()`, though there are parts of the lifecycle where this will return `null`. Inside `onCreateView()`, though, this is safe.

So write this instead:

```
frombottom=  AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.frombottom);
```